# Is there a way to tighten the throttle cable on a 2004 Echo?

Tags: toyota, throttle, echo

Curious whether it's possible and how to do tighten up the throttle cable on my 2004 Toyota Echo manual.

Comment: Before we go giving you advice as to how to tighten the cable, maybe you could give us some information as to what is wrong and why you are trying to "tighten" it? What you consider tightening may not be exactly what I'm thinking right now.

Comment: There's a noticeable deadspot when I put the foot on the pedal to before the engine revs. 

There's slack when I open the hood.

Comment: I believe what @Nick has suggested is what you are looking to do then. You should have a little slack in the cable, but not a bunch. You don't want any tension on it as this will mess with your throttle position and where your engine idles at. You should be attempting to adjust it at the bracket (upper left hand corner of the pic which he provided).

Comment: Ah I see. I plan to use my ODB2 scanner to keep an eye that I didn't alter idle. 

Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 5):

The Toyota Echo (and most cars pre-2011ish) uses a cabled throttle assembly, so you should be able to tighten the cable fairly easily.

Look for the following in your engine bay
[image]

You see the nut to the left of the arrow, that's where you can tighten the system.

A good link is http://www.toyotaownersclub.com/forums/topic/112409-a-guide-to-adjusting-the-throttle-cable/ , which is for a Corolla, but covers the basics of cable adjustment for cabled throttles.